# Expo fonts in global stylesheet

Tags: react-native, exponentjs, expo

I am using Expo and need to use custom fonts in my global stylesheet. Expo [documents](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v14.0.0/guides/using-custom-fonts.html) this, however it is not relevant in my case since componentDidMount() only executes within a class:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

My global stylesheet looks like this:

```
const React = require('react-native');

import {
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

const { StyleSheet } = React;

export default {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I hit this error because the file in which I wrapped my app with a component that loaded my font was exporting the wrong component!

Answer (score 1):

Font loading in Expo is "lazy" in the sense that you can create a StyleSheet object that references a font before it is loaded. For example, this code is valid:

```
async function exampleAsync() {
  let stylesheet = StyleSheet.create({
    fancyText: {
      ...Expo.Font.style('open-sans-bold'),
    },
  });

  await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
  });
}
```

So you don't need to call `Expo.Font.loadAsync` within `componentDidMount` necessarily, and it's OK to call `StyleSheet.create` and `Expo.Font.style` before the font is loaded.

What's important is that you wait for `Expo.Font.loadAsync` to complete before you render a component whose style uses the loaded font.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just loading fonts within the Navigation file, and was then able to access these fonts in my global stylesheet and throughout my app.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply in your root/top component add a state flag checking whether font async already finished.

Then add a condition in your render method to be sure that your child components will be rendered only after Fonts were succesfully loaded.  Pls see example

```
     export default class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        fontLoaded: false,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAssetsAsync();
      }

      async loadAssetsAsync() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
         'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
        });;

        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
      }

      render() {
        if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
          return <AppLoading />;  // render some progress indicator
        }

        return (
          <Navigator />    //render your child components tree
        );
      }
    }
```